# How to view kafka message?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there any way I can view the message content sent to kafka for a given topic? Say some thing like view last 5 messages for this topic, if that it possible.

Comment: [KaDeck](https://www.kadeck.com) is a free "Kafka Topic/Message Browser" which runs on Mac, Linux and Windows as Desktop Application. It also supports Avro (Schema Reg + Embedded), Json, String, etc... If you need a webservice you need to go for the enterprise edition though.

Comment: Upvote the `kcat` answer for simplicity

Answer (score 207, accepted):

You can use console consumer to view messages produced on some topic:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

Comment: This command also required --zookeeper details , I added those like - ./kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test. But now I get - kafka.common.ConsumerRebalanceFailedException: console-consumer-18088_sp-1496052524018-50bb9338 can't rebalance after 4 retries
 at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener.syncedRebalance(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:660)
 at

Comment: Which is a separate issue. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563401/rebalancing-issue-while-reading-messages-in-kafka

Comment: Use bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --new-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning

Comment: `bootstrap-server` vs. `zookeeper` is a matter of kafka version.

Comment: WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-22072] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Comment: @vatsalmevada 
In my case I see the warnings:
 WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-85244-1, groupId=console-consumer-85244] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
^CProcessed a total of 0 messages
But we have SASL PLAIN authentication enabled (without SSL), can it be the reason? and how connection has to be established in that case?

Comment: For windows

.bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topic-name --from-beginning

Comment: Checkout `kcat`

Answer (score 24):

On server where your admin run kafka find **kafka-console-consumer.sh** by command `find . -name kafka-console-consumer.sh` then go to that directory and run for read message from your topic

`./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning --max-messages 10`

note that in topic may be many messages in that case I use **--max-messages** key

Comment: For windows .bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topic-name --from-beginning

Comment: Checkout the `kcat` answer

Answer (score 4):

Use the Kafka consumer provided by Kafka :

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server BROKERS --topic TOPIC_NAME
```

It will display the messages as it will receive it. Add `--from-beginning` if you want to start from the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

A simple terminal-based tool you can use is [kcat](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/app-development/kafkacat-usage.html).

```
# Display values
kcat -C -b <bootstrap_server_host:port> -t <topic>

# Display key and values separated by ':'
kcat -C -K : -b <bootstrap_server_host:port> -t <topic>
```

Note however that deserialization options are a bit limited since it doesn't support protobuf, but it does support Avro.

Answer (score 2):

If you're wondering why the original answer is not working. Well it might be that you're not in the home directory. Try this:

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

Answer (score 1):

If you doing from windows folder, I mean if you are using the kafka from windows machine

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --<topic-name> test --from-beginning
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the easiest way is, if you are using a JetBrains IDE (I don't know if the others has that plugin), download Big Data Tools plugin.

It will be added to right toolbar. You can connect to your Kafka Server. If it is on localhost the URL of the server is set to default to `127.0.0.1:9092`.

After connected successfully, the Kafka will be added your bottom toolbar. Click it and click the `Add Consumer` button. Select your topic to consume, and start consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Old version includes `kafka-simple-consumer-shell.sh` (https://kafka.apache.org/downloads#1.1.1) which is convenient since we do not need `cltr+c` to exit.

For example

```
kafka-simple-consumer-shell.sh --broker-list $BROKERIP:$BROKERPORT --topic $TOPIC1 --property print.key=true --property key.separator=":"  --no-wait-at-logend
```