# Test kafka consumer without start service on docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have multiple microservice (spring boot), and some of them communicate with other by using kafka message.

When I want to test kafka consumer on service 1 (check is that kafka can receive message from other), I need to start docker for service 1, then start docker for service 2 and then debug to service 2 with some change to test.

Is it able to send kafka to service 1 (run on docker) without start service 2?
How can do it. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question... You can download the Kafka CLI tools or otherwise run a Kafka producer outside of Docker, in either case you need some code running somewhere doing the same thing as the service

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to

> check is that kafka can receive message from other

you can start service 1, and then read the messages on kafka using kafka-console-consumer.sh

Take a look here: [How to view kafka message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239027/how-to-view-kafka-message)